# Gracenote, exception database in C# sample

Tags: c#, sqlite, sample, gracenote

When I try to run sample in GNSDK for C#, an exception fire for enable local database sqlite.
In GNSDK log i see this

```
Local Lookup Initialize: Version 3.07.0.2861  Built 2014-10-28 01:46-0700
2014-12-29 11:26:08.406     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] gnsdk_lookup_local_get_build_date
2014-12-29 11:26:08.519     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] gnsdk_lookup_local_get_version
2014-12-29 11:26:12.371     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] gnsdk_lookup_local_storage_location_set( gnsdk_lookup_local_gdball, ../../../sample_db )
2014-12-29 11:26:12.372     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] lookup_local_storage_location_set( gnsdk_lookup_local_storage_primary_identifier, gnsdk_lookup_local_gdball, ../../../sample_db )
2014-12-29 11:26:14.460     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] gnsdk_lookup_local_get_build_date
2014-12-29 11:26:14.506     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] gnsdk_lookup_local_get_version
2014-12-29 11:26:20.531     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] gnsdk_lookup_local_storage_info_count( gnsdk_lookup_local_gdbmdata, gnsdk_lookup_local_gdb_version, 5DCE53C )
2014-12-29 11:26:20.532     DEBUG       GNSDK Local     0x00001840  [api_trace] lookup_local_storage_location_get( gnsdk_lookup_local_storage_primary_identifier, gnsdk_lookup_local_gdbmdata, 5DCE524 )
2014-12-29 11:26:20.532     DEBUG       GNSDK SQLite    0x00001840  sqlite_storage_helpers.c[412]   Storage connection: gn_mdata.gdb
**2014-12-29 11:26:20.533   WARNING     GNSDK Local     0x00001840  lookup_local_storage_helpers.c[219] Failed to open storage group: 'gn_mdata.gdb'**
2014-12-29 11:26:20.533     DEBUG       GNSDK Manager   0x00001840  [api_trace] gnsdk_manager_error_info
```

Do you have some idea to help me ?

Comment: Is this the exception? Show us the exception.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception? Did you debug the application to see when and why it happens? Show us your code.

Comment: The GnException ErrorDescription is "Local data store not found", the ErrorCode is 279250176 and the ErrorApi is "gnsdk_lookup_local_storage_info_count"
The code is the "musicid_album_text" GNSDK sample.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the local mode, you need a special license file for that.

Make sure to understand there is a difference between using a local sqlite cache for queries, which is going to work for you and having a local metadata database, which you will not be able to use (except if you have a commercial agreement to do so).

Comment: Hello, I don't have problem with my licence file. It's the online mode who required a specific licence. A registration it's required to online use.

Comment: As you can see in the output log, the SDK is trying to make local lookups using a local database that you do not have:  lookup_local_storage_helpers.c[219] Failed to open storage group: 'gn_mdata.gdb', makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I know, but in online mode, I don't have the licence for online mode then what's the correct mode to run sample ?

Comment: The correct mode is online. You cannot run it offline. Go here to create an account: https://developer.gracenote.com/  
There you will be able to generate the licence file you need.

Comment: Yes, I am registered on the site, I create a licence file for my application. This file, I use in my code but with the online mode, I have a error message who said I don't have the right licence for this using. :-(

Comment: Ok, let's be a little concrete ;)
What's the client id? only post the first part of the client id, the one before the : or the -
Have you modified the sample? I'll try on my side if you want.
What is your username on the developer portal?